# Is Square of unbiased estimator is unbiased again?

Tags: statistics, estimation

I am kind of new in here.

I have a question that bothering me that the square of an unbiased estimator is an unbiased estimator. I know that it is not the case but how I can prove that? Using $V(o) = E[o^2] - (E[o])^2$ or some other technique.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is that, if $\hat{\theta}=E(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a parameter in a statistical distribution($\hat{\theta}$ is its unbaised estimator), then why $\hat{\theta}^2\neq E(\theta^2)$? (i.e. Why $\hat{\theta}^2$ is NOT unbaised)

This can be seen by applying the formula
$$
Var(\theta^2)=E(\theta^2)-[E(\theta)]^2\geq0.
$$
So
$$
E(\theta^2)> [E(\theta)]^2
$$
when $Var(\theta)\neq0$.
So in general, $\hat{\theta}^2=[E(\theta)]^2\neq E(\theta^2)$.

Comment: How can you guarantee that variance is not zero always. Variance could be zero all the time.

Comment: But then you have $MSE(\hat \theta, \theta) = Var(\hat \theta) + Bias(\hat \theta) = 0 + 0 = 0$ which "too good" to be true for an estimator.